# While(true)-loop not breaking, scanner

Tags: java

I have a problem with some code. When I try to break my loop using "quit" it wont stop. If I begin with typing quit, it breaks as intended but the second time the loop runs and I type quit it's not breaking. What is the problem?

```
public static void interactionLoop() {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ssn = null;
    String message = null;
    int accountNr;
    double amount;
    while(true) {
        for(Customers aCustomer : Customers.getCustomerList()) {
            System.out.println(aCustomer.getName() + ", " + aCustomer.getSsn());
        }
        System.out.println("Choose a customer by using SSN.");
        System.out.print(">> ");
        ssn = input.nextLine();
        if(ssn.equals("quit")) {
            break;
        }
        Customers theChosenCustomer = Customers.getCustomerBasedOnSSN(ssn);
        ArrayList<Accounts> accList = theChosenCustomer.getAccountList();

        for(Accounts anAccount : accList) {
            if(anAccount instanceof Savings) {
                System.out.print("(Savings, " + anAccount.getAccountNr() + ")" + "\n");
            }

            if(anAccount instanceof Loans) {
                System.out.print("(Loans, " + anAccount.getAccountNr() + ")" + "\n");
            }

        }

        System.out.print("Enter the account that you want to work with using the account number:\n>> ");
        accountNr = input.nextInt();

        Accounts chosenAccount = theChosenCustomer.getSpecificAccount(accountNr);

        System.out.println("Account balance: "+chosenAccount.getBalance());

        for(Transaction t : chosenAccount.getTransaction()) {
            System.out.println(t.getDateAndTime().getTime() +", " + t.getComment() +": " + t.getAmount());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount of money you wish you withdraw or deposit: ");

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            amount = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            if(chosenAccount.isValid(amount)){
                System.out.print("Please enter a comment: ");
                message = input.nextLine();
                Calendar transdatetime = Calendar.getInstance();
                chosenAccount.makeTransaction(new Transaction(transdatetime,message,amount));
                System.out.println("");
                interactionLoop();



            }
        }





    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accountNr = input.nextInt();
```

From 2nd time onwards  `Scanner` scans `Integer` from the Std InpuStream but then the **newline** remains which is taken by

```
ssn = input.nextLine();
```

due to which your program does not quit. Same goes for `double`. Better use

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

then use `reader.readLine()` and parse it into your desired data type. Eg. `Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine())`

Comment: Thank you Aniket. I tried with your solution but the problem remained. It's the exact same error as before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put `input.nextLine();` after `accountNr = input.nextInt();` too.

Comment: So I shouldn't use the bufferedReader at all? I'm confused right now.

Comment: I don't see any bufferedReader in your updated code.